# Python function to decompose a number in all possible sum of squares

Tags: python, math

I am trying to solve this problem for days now, no strategy came to my mind. We need to decompose a number into all different possible ways it can be summed up from squares of other non repeating numbers.

Example: The number `50` can be decomposed in 3 different ways:

```
7^2 + 1^2   =   3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2   =   1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 6^2   =   50
```

We need to know in how many ways can a random number be decomposed.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. You need to show your code - [mre] and ask specific question.

Comment: It is a specific question, there must be a theory behind it that I cannot find. This surely is not a random problem.

Comment: Surely there is theory, however StackOverflow is about programing. We are glad to help with problems with your code, not general theory. You may want to try https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let nsp( n) be the number of such partitions of n, and nspl( n, k) be the number of such partitions with the least number in it being k
Then

```
nsp( n) = Sum{ k*k <= n | nspl( n, k) }
nspl( n, k) = 1, if n==k*k
              nspl( n-k*k, k+1), otherwise
```